# Module Drag Boxes in JS

Tags: javascript

is there a library in javascript where i can let the user drag and drop boxes and configure?  like igoogle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out [jQuery UI](http://jqueryui.com) for [jQuery](http://jquery.com).  It has a [Draggable](http://jqueryui.com/demos/draggable/) class that will allow you to drag and drop elements.

Answer (score 1):

Checkout this plugin [Easy Widgets](http://plugins.jquery.com/project/easywidgets) that was inspired by [this tutorial](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/javascript-ajax/inettuts/) on nettuts that goes over how to build an iGoogle like interface using jQuery in detail. The plugin's home page is down but the source code is available, and you can still see a demo of the nettuts tutorial in action [here](http://nettuts.s3.amazonaws.com/127_iNETTUTS/demo/index.html).

Answer (score 1):

Check ScriptAculous to enable drag and drop

```
    http://wiki.github.com/madrobby/scriptaculous/draggable 
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/script.aculo.us/scriptaculous_drag_drop.htm
```